# Radio Button Checked with styled components

Tags: reactjs, styled-components

i'm trying to make a react project with styled components, and i want to use a radio button, but when i try to add css to the radio when it's checked it didn't work as i expected, can you help me?

```
const RadioGroup = styled.div`
    border: solid 3px #332f35;
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 20px;
    border-radius: 10px;
    overflow: hidden;

      input[type=radio] {
        position: absolute;
        visibility: hidden;
        display: none;
  }

  label {
      color: lighten(#332f35,40%);
      display: inline-block;
      cursor: pointer;
      font-weight: bold;
      padding: 5px 20px;
  }

  input[type=radio]:checked + label{
  color: lighten($bg,60%);
  background: #ff9000;
}

input[type=radio] + label {
  border-left: solid #a1a1a1;
}
`
```

this is the styled component i'm trying to use in the Radio button, thanks guys!